# React navigation dependencies issue

Tags: reactjs, dependencies, react-navigation

I am trying to install @react-navigation/bottom-tabs@next. I have some dependency issues.
I have tried clear the cache, re-install all the packages.
Thank you so much.

My react-navigation version is 6.x.
My package.json file looks like

```
"dependencies": {
"@react-native-masked-view/masked-view": "^0.2.3",
"@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.0-next.2",
"@react-navigation/stack": "^5.14.4",
"native-base": "^2.15.2",
"react": "17.0.1",
"react-native": "0.64.0",
"react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.10.3",
"react-native-network-info": "^5.2.1",
"react-native-reanimated": "^2.1.0",
"react-native-safe-area-context": "^3.2.0",
"react-native-screens": "^3.1.1",
"react-native-splash-screen": "^3.2.0",
"react-native-vector-icons": "^7.1.0"
},
```

Comment: Try `npm i @react-navigation/bottom-tabs@6.0.0-next.0` https://www.npmjs.com/package/@react-navigation/bottom-tabs/v/6.0.0-next.0. You say: *"I have some dependency issues"*. What is that some error message?

Comment: I uninstalled react-navigation 6.0 and install 5.9.4 and @react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^5.11.10" It seems working fine now. Thank you so much for your reply.